# how to replace words in string using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have a string,

```
mystr = 'public\uploads\file-1490095922739.jpg';
```

i want to replace

> public\uploads

with " ", so that i just want to extract only file name ie

> file-1490095922739.jpg

or like,

> \uploads\file-1490095922739.jpg

how can i do this, is there any methods for this in js or can we do it by replace method.

i am performing the following steps,

```
var imagepath1;
var imagepath = 'public\uploads\file-1490095922739.jpg';
unwantedChar = 'public|uploads';
regExp = new RegExp(unwantedChar , 'gi');
imagepath = imagepath.replace(regExp , '');
imagepath1 = imagepath;
$scope.model.imagepath = imagepath1.replace(/\\/g, "");
```

please suggest me optimized method.

Comment: Is the part you are looking for always the part after the last `\\` character?

Comment: no i want to remove the word "public\uploads" so that i remain with the filename "file.jpg".

Comment: So that is not the same thing? In other words, could `public\uploads` be followed by anything else than a single filename separated by a backslash?

Comment: yes exactly!!!!!

Comment: So what should happen if the input is `\uploads\file-1490095922739.jpg`?

Comment: i have img tag something like this,,,,,,, <img src="/url/public/uploads/{{model.imagepath}}" alt="some name" width="100" height="100">,,, imagepath wil get the filename from that particular folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var input = "public\\uploads\\file-1490095922739.jpg";
var result = input.replace("public\\uploads\\", "");
```

This is what you're looking for, no need for fancy regexs :). More information about replace can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the issue - but wouldn't this work?

```
var mystr = 'public\uploads\file-1490095922739.jpg';
var filename = mystr.replace('public\uploads', '');
```

Comment: i tried the same but it is throwing the following error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence

Comment: Ah yeah as @Dax pointed out - you need to escape the slashes. :-)

Comment: yeah that's working fine, need to escape the slashes :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about just doing:

```
var imagepath = 'public\\uploads\\file-1490095922739.jpg';
$scope.model.imagepath = imagepath.replace('public\\uploads\\', '');
```

instead of using a bunch of unnecessary variables?

This way you're getting the file path, removing `public\uploads\` and then setting the file path to `$scope.model.imagepath`

Note that this will only work if the image file path always matches `'public\uploads\*FILENAME*'`.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence,,,,,,,,,, the above stated logic works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the part of the string after the last backslash character, you can use this:

```
var filename = mystr.substr(mystr.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

Also note that you need to escape the backslash characters in your test string:

```
var mystr = 'public\\uploads\\file-1490095922739.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = '/anysource/anypath/myfilename.gif';
var filename = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1,url.length);
```

Search for the last forward slash, and slice the string (+1 because you don't want the slash), with the length of the string to get the filename. This way, you don't have to worry about the path is at all times.